# Unable to mock typeorm datasource

Tags: jestjs, nestjs, typeorm

Below is the file where I am trying to mock datasource. but Getting error as

TypeError: Cannot set property DataSource of [object Object] which has only a getter

```
import { AppService } from '../services';
import typeorm = require('typeorm');

describe("Tests for AppService", () => {
    beforeAll(() => {
        typeorm.DataSource = jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
            manager: {
                find: jest.fn(),
                query: jest.fn(),
            }
        })

      });
      
    it("should call getServices", () => {
        const AS = new AppService();
        AS.getServices(1);
        expect(typeorm.DataSource).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
})
```

datasource file

```
import { DataSource } from 'typeorm';
import { services } from '../entity/services';
import { versions } from '../entity/versions';

export const connectDB = new DataSource({
  type: 'postgres',
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 5431,
  username: 'postgres',
  password: 'password',
  database: 'test',
  synchronize: true,
  logging: true,
  entities: [services, versions],
  subscribers: [],
  migrations: [],
});

connectDB
  .initialize()
  .then(() => {
    console.log(`Data Source has been initialized`);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error(`Data Source initialization error`, err);
  });

export default connectDB;
```

And I am using it like,

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Like } from 'typeorm';
import connectDB from '../config/db_connection';
import { services } from '../entity/services';
import { versions } from '../entity/versions';

// handle errors //
// write function description

@Injectable()
export class AppService {
  public getServices(id: number): Promise<versions[]> {
    return connectDB.manager.find(versions, {
      relations: {
        service: true,
```

Is there any better way to mock typeorm datasource in jest.

Thanks

Comment: How are you using the datasource? That may help in making an easier way to mock it

Comment: @JayMcDoniel  Updated the post with all details.

Comment: Any reason you don't use `@nestjs/typeorm` and `@InjectDataSource()`?

Comment: I am using typeorm

Comment: But are you using `@nestjs/typeorm`? It's a wrapper around typeorm for easier integration with NestJS applications (most of the time).

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I implement it in a repo of mine:

```js
import { DataSource } from 'typeorm'

const makeDataSourceMock = (): DataSource => ({
  name: 'any_data_source',
  options: { database: 'any_database' },
  destroy: jest.fn(),
  manager: { save: jest.fn() },
  getRepository: jest.fn(() => ({
    clear: jest.fn()
  })),
  entityMetadatas: [
    { name: 'any_entity_name' }
  ]
}) as any
```

Here is the complete test file if you want to take a look: https://github.com/leal32b/webapi-nodejs/blob/main/test/core/3.infra/persistence/postgres/client/postgres-client.unit.test.ts